# SQL Query syntax for Pivot Table output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table name **PatientInsurance** which has two columns Priority and PlanName.

Some patients have more than one insurance and some don't have.

I am fetching some records by joining the **Patient** Table and **PatientInsurance** Table.

```
    From PatientInsurance Table :- Sample set of record for a specific patient.

    Priority      PlanName
    1             ADVANCE
    2             LOYALTY



Case when PatientInsurance.Priority = 1 , then output.PrimaryInsurance = PlanName
Case when PatientInsurance.Priority =2 , then output.SecondaryInsurance  = PlanName

Expected output as 

    PatientName PrimaryInsurance   SecondaryInsurance
     John        Advance             Loyalty
     Asif        BCBS 
     Merin       Advance              BCBS
```

How to write a query to display record in a single line output?

Added a sqlfiddle, Please

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57d47/2

Comment: Not very clear to me,create a fiddle.

Comment: Okay , please give me a minute

Comment: yes, sqlfiddle please.

Comment: I am just working on getting a fiddle. Please give me few mins

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57d47/2

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a pivot for that, you can use subqueries. You didn't specify the exact schema but it could be something like:

```
select PatientName,
     (select PlanName from PatientInsurance
          where PatientInsurance.PatientId = Patient.PatientId
          and PatientInsurance.Priority = 1) as PrimaryInsurance,
     (select PlanName from PatientInsurance
          where PatientInsurance.PatientId = Patient.PatientId
          and PatientInsurance.Priority = 2) as SecondaryInsurance
from Patient
```

Comment: I got atleast 10 tables returning the SELECT QUERY with JOIN conditions. So, is there a way to replace the subquery with JOIN QUERY or any other syntax format.

Comment: @goofyui Hard to say without seeing your query.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/57d47/3  - Your query works. Thanks. But as i mentioned, i have 10 tables in the Join Query

Comment: added the actual query. Please help me to rewrite the syntax

Comment: You can still just add those 2 subqueries to your select list, that should work.

Comment: You cannot really join as you would have to do it twice and it would create duplicate records for some patients.

Comment: @Szymon - Thanks for your answer. Can you tell me if my answer okay too ?

Comment: How to combine your subquery syntax to my existing Query ? Because in my existing query, i have already mentioned about Patient Table and PatientInsurance Table.

Comment: Thanks Szymon, creating a view table. That will solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Were you look for pivot query ?

```
Select 
Pvt.PatientName, 
Pvt.[1] as PrimaryInsurance,
Pvt.[2] as SecondaryInsurance
From(
select P.PatientName , 
PIn.[Priority], 
PIn.PlanName
from Patient as P
inner join PatientInsurance as PIn
on P.Patid = Pin.PatId
) as normal  
PIVOT(
Max(PlanName)
For[Priority]
In([1],[2]) 
) as Pvt
```

It give me the output you have ask.

Comment: Yes, that does work on in the limited sample given in the question but it won't be suitable for the full query.

Comment: @Szymon - Please tell me why it will not be suitable for the full query. Thank you.

Comment: There's a lot of other columns returned in the full query. OP doesn't want to pivot them, he just needs to have those 2 he asked about. In my opinion, he didn't really wanted a pivot, he just wanted to have 2 additional columns for each record.

Comment: @Szymon - Thaq big query is so ugly, I am not even looking at it.

Comment: Well, ugly or not, a solution should solve a problem in such a way that it's most useful.

Comment: @Szymon - Agree. But, the patient will become more ill by the time this gigantic query executes :P

Comment: Imagine the nurse telling you, sorry ! An SQL server query timed out. Come tomorrow for your meds :P

Comment: Borat , Thanks. Your answer is also correct. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am getting an error message. To set the Compatibility level of Database.
Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature.